# Activating non-active secondary monitor

Tags: windows, display

I bought ATI radeon 5450 video card to have 2 monitors on one HP desktop. The 2nd display was showing not activated, but the choice boxes were ticked permanent. What do i do to activate secondary monitor?. Thanks

Comment: Can you please confirm that both monitors are plugged into the graphics card and one isn't plugged into the onboard graphics (VGA/DVI)

Comment: What version of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed ATI drivers, on Desktop->Properties->Settings->Advanced -> there should be ATI tab with settings regarding 2 monitors setup